# Не отправляется письмо

Tags: php

Почему-то php-скрипт не отправляет данные на почту. Я даже сделал запись в файл, чтобы задебажить получение данных, но запись не происходит. Я что-то сделал не так?

```
<?php
// config
$adminemail="andrewdymov@gmail.com";
$date=date("d.m.y");
$time=date("H:i");

// confirm data
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
$email = $_POST["mail"]; 
$subject = $_POST["subject"]; 
$message = $_POST["message"];

if (!preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", strtolower($email))) { header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500); 
} else { 
$msg="<p>Отправлено: $time $date</p>
<p>Имя: $name</p> 
<p>E-mail: $email</p> 
<p>Тема: $subject</p> 
<p>Сообщение: $message</p>";  

mail("$adminemail", "$subject", "$msg"); 
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "a"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи 
$test = fwrite($fp, $msg); } ?>
```

Comment: Часто ошибка с самим сервером, вы на local machine или на shared host? в плане кода все ок

Comment: У меня VPS. Ubuntu 16.04, nginx проксирует Apache.

Comment: Какой response code возвращает сервер? Права на запись test.txt есть?

Comment: @Firepro Если отправляю правильный email-адрес, то регулярку он проходит и возвращает 200. Если отправляю заведомо неверный email, то возвращает 500 как и задумано. То есть, данные до скрипта доходят, но почему-то не записываются в файл/не отправляются на почту.

Comment: var_dump($test); - в конце подставьте, и посмотрите что выводит Вам в случае ввода нормального email? Если false, надо настроить права, если >0 - запись успешна. Почта не отправляется, потому что у вас почтовый сервер на VPS видимо не настроен, поищите материал по настройке sendmail или postfix, последний легче настраивать. А еще надо не забыть про SPF, PTR, DKIM, иначе почта будет отправляться но не приходить, логи почты обычно в /var/log/mail.log

Answer (score 1):

```
mail($adminemail, $subject, $msg");
```

Попробуйте вот так